# Mac Book Pro - 5 400 tr/min or 7 200 tr/min?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I'm buying a mac book pro (this one: http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MC723LL/A?mco=MjEyOTY4OTQ).

My doubt is:

1. 5400 tr/min 750Gb or
2. 7200 tr/min 500Gb ?

I would appreciate the extra space but I'm afraid of the 5400 be really really slower than 7200.
What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not hammering the hard drive all the time, say by doing HD video work, then you're not going to notice. In that case, the 5400 might be better because it is larger, takes less power and is less likely to fail.

Comment: My experience is the higher RPM drives are actually manufactured to a higher standard and fail less often than consumer drives. Do you have any links to studies showing that the drives Apple uses are more prone to failing or industry wide data on 5400/7200 drive reliability?

Comment: Nothing handy. This was from an article years ago when 5400 was the norm and 7200 was fast, not recently. Please elaborate what you mean by "higher RPM", since 7200 is the norm these days and 10000 would be "higher". Also elaborate your implied link of "slower" to "consumer"; for example, Seagate makes slow-spinning server drives (LP series) for where heat and power consumption in the datacenter is the major issue. Also, most consumer drives are 7200 these days.

Comment: Even today, MacBook pro and mac mini still ship with 5400 rpm drives unless you upgrade. I was going to keep the 10k and 15k drives out since they don't normally make it in a portable :-)